# Running Django tests in Docker Windows

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to run the tests of a Django project inside a container which is running on a Windows host. The problem is that when I run the command: `python manage.py test` I get the following erros for all my files:

```
myproj/tests/tests_forms/test_product_form.py is executable; skipped
```

I've checked the file permissions and all of them have execute permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x`. I've tried to change this using `chmod`, but it doesn't work probably because I am running docker on Windows.

Is there a way around this? Maybe some way to force Django to run the tests regardless of the file permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using nose (or django-nose), executable python scripts are skipped by default. According to [the docs](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#cmdoption-exe), it's because "they may not be import-safe".

If you run `nosetests` directly, you can use the `--exe` argument to include executable files: `nosetests --exe`.

If you're using the django-nose package, you can use the `NOSE_INCLUDE_EXE` environment variable to accomplish the same thing: `NOSE_INCLUDE_EXE=1 python manage.py test`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't have that option. I am running a very old version of Django: 1.7.11.

Comment: @Felipe I updated the answer to work with the Django management commands. I've tested this with a Django 1.7.11 project where the test file is executable (777)

Comment: This command did the trick for me: `NOSE_INCLUDE_EXE=1 python manage.py test`.  Thanks for the help.